# Can I modify HTTP request line (server-side) prior to processing by Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2

On Centos (version 6) using Apache 2.2.15, is there a way of modifying the initial request line server-side prior to Apache processing it? I would like to be able to take a request:

POST /somedirectory/somescript.php\tHTTP/1.1

and change it to read

POST /somedirectory/somescript.php HTTP/1.1

Specifically, the "\t" character in the first example is a tab character and it appears that Apache rejects this as an invalid request and returns a status code 400.

I imagine using any extension (such as mod_rewrite) will not work, since Apache will have rejected the request before forwarding it.

Comment: Don't fix a broken client on the server. - Fix the client.

Comment: Generally I would agree with you. In a situation where this was practicable, I would. This is a very specific case where fixing the client is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

In RFC 7230 section 3.1.1 ("Request line") states the following:

> A request-line begins with a method token, followed by a single space
>   (SP), the request-target, another single space (SP), the protocol
>   version, and ends with CRLF.

This means that the request you're seeing with the '\t' tab character is not a valid HTTP request and thus Apache HTTPd responds with "400 Bad request".

You can probably make this work if your really have to, but you will need some kind of custom written proxy in front of your Apache HTTPd that rewrites the request lines.

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-3.5 indicates that white space may also be accepted and a tab constitutes white space (specifically paragraph 4). The original client clearly felt it was being compliant (or the programmer simply used a tab instead of a space) and historically it worked. I was coming to the same conclusion as you with regard to proxying the request so have upvoted your response accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: yeah, but allowing whitespace where only a SP is allowed is MAY which means nobody implemented it unless it was trivial. Furthermore the RFC discourages this in the next paragraph where splitting on whitespace is deemed a possible security issue.
So yes, it is still "be liberal in what you accept" and there may be webserver or http-proxy software out there allowing whitespace and not violating any RFC. It is just unlikely.

Comment: In this particular instance, replacing a tab character with a space character is not considered a significant security issue in the context of the use, but I am not really wanting to debate this. Ultimately, all that I am asking is if something is possible in Apache and it would appear to not be the case. Thanks for taking the time to respond.